# Internet connection via cable to wifi router in bridge mode works for some, but not all computers

Tags: internet, bridge

a curious problem is driving me crazy here. I am using a secondary wifi router set to bridge mode to access internet from the primary wifi router. My desktop PC is connected through cable to the secondary router. Now, I needed to reinstall the operating system because an update went wrong. Fortunatelly I decided to buy a better disk before formating and selling the old one. Now I have two win10 bootable disks in my desktop. All settings I could think of are set identicaly on both win10 instalations - simpy put, everything is set on automatic. When I boot from the old one, the internet works flawlessly. When I boot from the new one, no internet connection. I can ping both main and secondary router. with good response. Even pinging 8.8.8.8 works. But no real internet. Troubleshooting says gateway not accessible even though everything. I even tried hoking up an old laptop via cable and it gets to internet fine. I ruled out MAC address filtering because that is the same in both instances. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your computer is connected to your network by an Ethernet connection. The old disk starts and connects fine.

The first thing to try in this situation is a new and updated wired NIC driver.  Find the best driver, uninstall the existing driver, install the new driver and restart.

If this does not work, reinstall Windows on this new disk.

**Follow up possibility:**  If your old system in the computer was not up to date, it is possible the wired NIC worked with the old system but not Windows 10 V2004.  You may wish to try a USB NIC. As I say, this is a less likely possibility.

Comment: Not it. I setup a bridged connection through my laptop and hooked the desktop to the laptop via Ethernet cable. This way I was able to get on the Internet and haave all drives updated. When I pluged back the cable connected to the router, no Internet. The weird thing is I can ping outside servers - including DNS servers - with good response, but no real Internet connection. Troubleshooting says DNS server not responding.

Comment: What does Not It mean.  Did you trying reinstalling Windows on the new Disk?  Did you try another USB LAN Card?

Comment: Both win 10 instances are completely uptodate. All settings I can think of are identical. The only difference between them I can see after running ipconfig /all is different DHCPv6 DUID and IAID parameters.

Comment: I meant "it was not it". No I didnt reinstali win10 this time. I tried mounting another disk with win10 instead. Again, cannot get on the internet. I am in process of instaling Linux on an old disk to see whether it will get on the Internet.

Comment: I dont have USB LAN card, but what would be the point? the on board net card woks fine with bridged connection from my laptop so the problem is probably not there. There must be some obscure hidden idiotic setting that makes my router not agree with ma desktop.

Comment: My additional part of the answer was that a less up to date Windows system (old disk) could work with a NIC, but there may be a compatibility issue with the newest version of Windows.  Obscure setting would be part of the old disk, not the new Windows, so you need to look carefully through old disk NIC settings.

Comment: I understand what you`re saying, but the two win10 are the same versions, all uptodate, including drivers. Today I even tried a long ethernet cable to the primary router and the internet works, so its probably not about the NIC at all. I feel like I should aim at the router (maybe there is some kind of filtering apart from physical MAC address) but I am afraid that by resetting it I might lose internet even for the old disk. This project might turn into trying to fix the old disk win10 and then creating an image of it to be transfered onto the new disk.

Comment: The router should not be suspect as everything else is working. Your new disk should not have any strange networks card properties and that is what makes me think: try another Network card.

Comment: I think you`re wrong about this. Notice I wrote that connecting the desktop to the primary router ended up in good Internet connection. Plus, I just pulled another disk, installed win10 and ended up with no connection trough the secondary router. Then I did the same with another motheboard. I even tried live Linux distribution. Same result. The obly two computers that the router will let on the Internet are my old disk win10, regardless of the motheboard it is on, and my old laptop.

Comment: Both had their connection set up the same time as the router. Now I am positive the router somehow filters for specific OS identity. Don`t know how, though, and most importantly, how to reproduce it. I am stuck.

Comment: I am working with your original question (please do not confuse this with another motherboard).  The computer works properly (you said) and with a new disk and new install of Windows 10 does not work (you said). So it must have been something inside the NIC you changed to adapt the old system. That is almost the only conclusion that can be drawn. Changing more including motherboard does not have work out the issue.

Comment: I don`t confuse anything. Just trying to rule out possibilities, and this one did rule out the NIC problem in my opinion. If a number of different devices on a llink have the same problem than you can`t keep looking into the firśt device for an error. Sorry mate, you`re being persistent, but I am affraid it won`t help me here.